# ASP.NET MVC 5 - архитектура сайта

Tags: алгоритм, asp.net, mvc, архитектура

Нужно сделать небольшой сайтик для голосовалки всяких вопросов. Пользователь заходит на сайт, сперва видит самые популярные голосовалки для новичков, голосует активно участвует в опросах. После, чтобы иметь возможность оставлять комменты и голосовать опросы с высшим рейтингом, придется регистрироваться.

Использовать куки для гостя, записать туда очки и после регистрации добавить эти очки к рейтингу. А если пользователь увидит куки и сменит значение на свои, то после регистрации эти значения отправятся на сервер и т.д. Или все хранить в базе либо в XML файлах на сервере? Тогда опасаюсь, что от запросов гостя сервер может упасть или еще что. Короче, полная каша в голове.

Comment: Здесь только вам решать чем вы готовы пожертвовать во благо отложенной регистрации и насколько вы доверяете своим пользователям.

Comment: @AndrewB, Здравствуйте. Я еще новичок в сишарп, учу по книге Адам Фримена и почти заканчиваю книгу. Прошло 2 месяца и решил придумать свою первую серьезную задачу в учебных целях, чтобы закрепить знания. Есть общее представление о приложении, мысленно все расположено по полочкам, только вот никак не получается построить цепочку. С чего начать проектирование, как моделировать данные, как вообще начать? и т.д. очень много вопросов в голове...

Comment: У вас очень широкий вопрос. Попробуйте начать с сайта [professorweb](http://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/gamestore/level1/). Ссылка ведет на пример разработки простого web приложения. Также можно поискать аналогичные статьи.

Comment: Несколько раз случайно попадал на этот сайт, но не обращал внимание. Благодарю.